# Model returns as null in view list enumeration

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, model

I am writing a .net core web app, I'm brand new to it just trying to pump some localhost SQL data to my front end view using models following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqD-NJf7-OM

I don't have any syntax errors and my db updates when I run add-migration and update-database. I am adding all the data to my Students table manually using the SQL server management studio and when I check the SQL server objects panel in visual studio I can see the changes being made to the table so it should at least be able to use the model to grab the data from the db and display it

but for some reason I am getting an error that my Model is null which causes the app to crash, I am able to get around this by using   `@if(Model != null)` however I want to figure out why my model doesn't seem to associate with the database and actually pull the data, here are some full examples of my code relating to the view and model.

I have checked my getters and setters which seem okay by default I also checked my connection string which is correct in my json settings. I'm not sure what I need to do here or if I need to add something to my studentDbContext file?

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=mylaptop\\MSSQLSERVER01; Database=Students; Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

view

```
 
 @model IEnumerable<tutorialfrontend.Models.Student>

<h1>index</h1>

<div class="container p-3">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Students List</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">create new student</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if(Model != null)
    {
        @if(Model.Count() > 0)
        {
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Grade</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach(var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Id</td>
                            <td>@item.grade</td>
                        </tr>

                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    }
    </div>
```

StudentController

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using tutorialfrontend.Data;
using tutorialfrontend.Models;

namespace tutorialfrontend.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private readonly StudentDbContext _db;

        public StudentController(StudentDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Student> objList = _db.Student;
            return View(objList);
        }
    }
}
```

StudentDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using tutorialfrontend.Models;

namespace tutorialfrontend.Data
{
    public class StudentDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> options) :base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Student.cs (Model)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tutorialfrontend.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
           [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string grade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

startup.cs

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

Comment: Can you share your action which pass  `IEnumerable<tutorialfrontend.Models.Student>` type data to view?

Comment: @YiyiYou I have edited it to show my StudentContoller file which is the controller handling the action using Index()

Comment: Try to check if `_db.Student` has value.